# CakePHP как авторизовываться по token'у и получать доступ к данным

Tags: авторизация, cakephp, auth

Выполняю два GET запроса с помощью AJAX, первый запрос - авторизация, второй запрос - получение данных. 
Второй запрос не работает, потому что с ним не передается никаких данных об авторизации.

Мне нужно после успешной авторизации генерировать хеш `$token=md5(username+password+secret_key)` и передавать его в теле ответа. Потом остальные запросы выполнять с этим хешом и авторизовываться по нему.
Подскажите, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

ну к примеру на `jQuery` можно сделать так:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "someUrl",
    type : 'GET',
    data : {
        someData : someData
    },
    success: function(data) {
        //c php получаем данные (к примеру JSON)
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $.ajax({
            url :"someUrl2",
            type :'GET',
            data :{
                someData2:
                obj.someData2
            },
            success:function(data2) {
                var obj2 = jQuery.parseJSON(data2);
                if (obj2.status == 'ok') {
                    //some code here
                }
            }
        })
    }
})
return false;
```